# How to QUERY with formating individual letters?

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, reference, string-formatting, google-query-language

I'm trying to add a QUERY by copying the individual formatting of each cell from one worksheet to another. Someway? thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, this is not possible to do with `QUERY` or any other formula. using a script is the only option you have.

transferring multiple individual colors from in-one-cell to another cell is not possible at this current version of the Google Sheets (nor at any previous versions):

[image: 0]